# Multiple stream sources with video-js

Tags: video.js

I'd like to have two m3u8 sources, so when one is not available it skips to the next one. Is this possible?

I usually do that with html5 video as this:

```
<video controls="" height="" poster="" width="">
<source src="xxx.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"></source>
<source src="xxx.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"></source>
</video>
```

In don't know how to do it with video.js, as just putting the two sources doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's what u need - [VideoJS Error Event](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Methodserror)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use proper spelling and grammar in your posts. Also, a short explanation of the link is better than just posting a link by itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! It seems to be the thing I want but I don't really know how to implement the code. Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to use it? Thanks